# How to set monospaced font for lstlisting and verbatim in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

How to set monospaced font for **lstlisting** and **verbatim** in Emacs? I use Emacs 23.2.1 + AUCTeX 11.86 with Tango theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbatim text is set in the face `font-latex-verbatim-face`, which inherits from the `fixed-pitch` face.

If the text is not in the right face (check with `M-x describe-text-properties` or “Edit / Text properties / Display properties”),  there's something wrong with your AUCTeX installation (where does it come from?) or with your configuration (what happens if you run `emacs -q`?).

If the text is in the right face, there's something wrong with your theme. What are the parameters of the `fixed-pitch` face (`M-x describe-face RET fixed-pitch RET`)? Do you have the same problem with another theme?

Comment: This is not actually a problem, but the code looks better in lstlisting and verbatim if editor use monospaced fonts.
I use Emacs on Windows Vista with Consolas font:
`(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Consolas-11")`
[screen1](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/2252/monospacedconsolas.png).
When I comment this line:
[screen2](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2594/monospaceddefault.png)
but it's not monospaced font.
AUCTeX come from [AUCTeX-for-Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html) and everything works fine.

Comment: I set Text Properties for `font-latex-verbatim-face` on `Font Family: Consolas` and now looks great. Thanks Gilles!